# Type mismatch MySQL

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I have a VBScript that takes some system resources and stores them in a variables and I want to write them to a MySQL table.

When I get to the SQL statement I am getting an error

> Type mismatch: '[string: "insert into monitor "]'

I have googled and know that it's trying to pass the wrong data to the datatype.

MySQL Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE monitor (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pcname VARCHAR(30),
  cpu decimal(4,2),
  hdd decimal(4,2),
  mem decimal(4,2),
  rdate TIMESTAMP
);
```

Sample output:

```
+----+-------------+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id | pcname      | cpu  | hdd   | mem   | rdate               |
+----+-------------+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | HOSTNAME-PC | 4.00 | 39.26 | 74.28 | 2016-04-21 12:16:04 |
+----+-------------+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

Set variables

```vb
Dim Connection
Dim ConnectionString
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL
dim cpu 
dim hdd 
dim mem
dim host
```

Get hostname and store in host:

```vb
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strRegValue = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Hostname"
strHostName = wshShell.RegRead( strRegValue )
host = strHostName
```

Get cpu and store in cpu:

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor WHERE Name = '_Total'")
For Each objItem In colItems
    cpu = objItem.PercentProcessorTime
Next
```

Get hdd space and store in hdd

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk Where Name='C:'",,48)
For Each objItem In colItems
    intFreeSpace = objItem.FreeSpace
    intTotalSpace = objItem.Size
    pctFreeSpace = Round((intFreeSpace/intTotalSpace)*100, 2)
    hdd = pctFreeSpace
Next
```

Get memory space and store in mem:

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
GB = 1024 *1024 * 1024
For Each objItem In colItems
    intTotal = Round(objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory / GB, 3)
Next
Set colItems1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory",,48)
For Each objItem1 In colItems1
    intAvail =  Round(objItem1.AvailableBytes / GB, 3)
Next
pctFree = Round((intAvail/intTotal)*100, 2)
mem = pctFree
```

SQL Statement getting error:

> "Type mismatch: '[string: "insert into monitor "]'"

```vb
SQL = "insert into monitor (pcname,cpu,hdd,mem) values ('"+host+"','"+cpu+"','"+hdd+"','"+mem+"')"
```

Rest of code:

```vb
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=servername; DATABASE=dbname; " &_
    "UID=username;PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3"

Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open ConnString

Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

If Recordset.EOF Then
    Wscript.Echo("No records returned.")
Else
    Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
      WScript.Echo Recordset("pcname")
      WScript.Echo Recordset("cpu")
      WScript.Echo Recordset("hdd")
      WScript.Echo Recordset("mem")
      WScript.Echo "<br>"   
      Recordset.MoveNext    
    Loop
End If

Recordset.Close
Set Recordset = Nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to create a recordset based on an insert query. Recordset's primary goal is to **display** data from the database, but there is nothing to display if you execute an insert query.

You have 2 options:

1. Execute the insert query using connection object's [Execute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

   ```vb
   Connection.Execute sql, , 128 --128=0x80=adExecuteNoRecords
   ```

Then open the recordset on the monitor table using a select or table name.

2. Open a recordset object on monitor table using a select and use the recordset object's [AddNew method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

   ```vb
   Recordset.Open "SELECT * FROM monitor", Connection, 1
   Recordset.AddNew
   Recordset.Fields("pcname").Value = xxx
   ...
   Recordset.Update
   ```

UPDATE:

As @Ekkehard.Horner noted: the decimal column's value should not be enclosed by single quotes. Although MySQL will silently convert the string to number (unless strict sql mode is enabled), but the right thing is not to pass numbers as strings.

Comment: In addition: The Decimals shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Should not, but will not cause any problems with mysql if they are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SQL = "insert into monitor (pcname,cpu,hdd,mem) values ('"+host+"','"+cpu+"','"+hdd+"','"+mem+"')"
```

to

```
SQL = "insert into monitor (pcname,cpu,hdd,mem) values ('" & host & "','" & cpu & "','" & hdd & "','" & mem & "')"
```

Should be all set

Comment: The Decimals shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: In vbs you can use both & and + for string concatenation, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156813.aspx

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all (the statement is still trying to insert strings into numeric fields).